# Tornado execution order

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

I am trying to understand and check how tornado executes coroutines.
I noticed a behavior which make me think that gen.coroutine doesn't work.

Look at the test below. It passes, I expected to get l = [ "S1", "BF", "S2", "S3" ] because when submain yields asyncSubMain it returns to event loop queue to pull next callback it should get "beforeYield", because it was scheduled earlier.

```
def test_call_coroutine_function(ioLoop):
    l = []

    def syncSubMain():
        return "Oh! at last I understood how tornado turns"

    @gen.coroutine
    def asyncSubMain():
        l.append("S2")
        return syncSubMain()

    def beforeYield():
        l.append("BF")

    @gen.coroutine
    def submain():
        l.append("S1")
        ioLoop.add_callback(beforeYield)
        y = yield asyncSubMain()            
        l.append("S3")
        raise gen.Return(y)

    @gen.coroutine
    def main():
        x = yield submain()
        raise gen.Return(x)

    assert ioLoop.run_sync(main).startswith("Oh!")
    assert l == ["S1", "S2", "S3", "BF"]
```

Following test behaves like I want and I don't event use @gen.coroutine.

```
def test_sync_all_async(ioLoop):
class C:
    f = 0
    l = []

    def mf(self):
        return 1

    # gen.coroutine is not needed and if just call a method
    # with gen_coroutine it's executed synchronously
    def m3(self, a):
        self.l.append(a)
        self.f = self.mf()

    def m2(self):
        self.l.append("A")
        ioLoop.add_callback(self.m3, "B")
        self.l.append("C")

    def m(self):
        self.m2()

c = C()
ioLoop.run_sync(c.m)
assert c.f == 1
assert c.l == ["A", "C", "B"]
```

I thought that @gen.coroutine is just a syntax sugar for the test above.
Out of these tests follows either it's not working or something different from an event loop with callbacks.

Comment: `y = yield asyncSubMain()` is suspending `submain` and waiting for the result of the call (a future) to be resolved. Your two examples are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I also realized that I took wrong example with function instead of procedure. What is the way to check yield returns control to the event loop and it's not a just sync call?

Comment: I'm not shure that realy neaded to know sync or async was coroutine... exactly, your coroutine will asynchronous only when you really switch context. For this you have to perform yield gen.sleep(0) or any other asynchronous operations with yield.